# Skipping lines of code - CSV Related

Tags: c#, csv, coded-ui-tests

This is more of a general question but maybe in my case it can be more specific ( I certainly hope )

I'm doing a Coded UI Test replacing values from input controls/elements with csv data.

The problem is that depending on some of the columns in the csv file the pages may have different controls.

Example :

```
 this.UIMap.ICParams.UITboxQuantityEditText = TestContext.DataRow["qtd_c_1"].ToString();
 this.UIMap.ICParams.UITboxQuantityEdit1Text = TestContext.DataRow["qtd_c_2"].ToString();
```

This would replace the values recorded in 2 fields with 2 columns in the csv, but **it is possible that I may only have the first control** ( which would make the code line `this.UIMap.ICParams.UITboxQuantityEdit1Text = TestContext.DataRow["qtd_c_2"].ToString();` along with the csv column `qtd_c_2` useless since the control wouldn't exist thus crashing the test)

I've tried setting the value in the csv file like this ( Spaced out so it looks more clean here ) :

```
[col1][qtd_c_1][qtd_c_2][col4][col5]
[  a ][   5   ][       ][  d ][  b ] <--------
[  c ][   4   ][   2   ][  x ][  z ]
```

As you can see the column `qtd_c_2` is blank which I typed like this : `a,,d` ( nothing between the commas ) which is different from `a,"",d`

**Is there a way to skip code lines or ignore csv columns ?**

I'm aware of the `continue` statement but the code is not explicitly a loop ( internally it is but that's another thing ).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I've read your question more that 3 times. Still I can't figure out what you mean with "_but it is possible that I may only have the first control ( which would make the 2nd code line along with the 2nd csv column useless since the control wouldn't exist)_" Where did the 2nd control/column go? "_Skip code lines?_" I think you mean conditional statements? Like the `if` statement?

Comment: And as you can see, the content of qtd_c_2 is `,`, but thats your separator. so you need to escape that or use another separator like `;`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen you see, the test is going through several pages and the layout of these pages is affected by certain values in the csv file, in this case the 2nd control doesn't exist ( which makes the 2nd line crash the test since it is expecting the control )

Comment: Also, can't I leave it blank ? not like `""` but something like a `null`

Comment: I think you should create a test per page. You shouldn't make 'one test to rule them all'.

Comment: It's one test with subtests inside of it , On each page I stop the recording and generate the code. Is that wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer im just trying to UNDERSTAND what you are saying.

```
[col1][col2][col3][col4][col5]
[a   ][5   ][    ][    ][  b ]
[    ][    ][    ][    ][    ]


UITboxQuantityEditText = TestContext.DataRow["col1"].ToString();
UITboxQuantityEdit1Text = TestContext.DataRow["col3"].ToString();
```

Given the above... why dont you just check if its null or set it to null or ignore it, base on if its null or not.

```
var valueCol1 = TestContext.DataRow["col1"];
if (valueCol1 == DBNull.Value)
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
```

Obviously this can be refactored and improved by creating functions and extensions that do this for you, I'm just trying to understand the requirement.

Comment: I'll update my question matching your formatting to make it clearer.

Comment: @Onilol yeah thanks!, i was going to do it for you but might of lost detail which is applicable which wouldn't be gd.

Comment: @Onilol, why cant you just check if its empty and are you SURE quote 'Is there a way to skip code lines or ignore csv columns ?' is worded correctly for what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: I could check if it's null, but I'm not looping through the code so in the case the 2nd control does not exist I'd need to avoid the next line, but there are more lines after it.

Comment: Yes, each page might have all of it's controls or not, but the csv covers all of them.

Comment: @Onilol, so do you only want to set them if there is a value for them in the Csv, or.... you will have to explain how you are dynamically handling the conditional controls.. you will need to explain more.

Comment: Yes I want to set them if the value exists in the csv, I have no clue on how I could handle the controls like that.. any tips ?

Comment: @Onilol so why cant you just check if there is a value, and if there is set it, otherwise skip.

Comment: @Onilol what do you mean? sorry but you are not very clear. Give actual code and then a comment 'how do i skip this..' next to the line you are talking about.

Comment: perhaps I can delete the question.. I'm trying some things here.